# Load View in Custom Helper Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

In CI 3 i can load view file in helper like this.

```
if ( !function_exists('render_admin_view') ) {
        function render_admin_view($filename, $data) {
            $ci = &get_instance();
            $dir = $ci->config->item('admin_dir');
            $ci->load->view($dir . 'common/header', $data);
            $ci->load->view($filename, $data);
            $ci->load->view($dir . 'common/menu', $data);
            $ci->load->view($dir . 'common/footer', $data);
        }
}
```

But in CI 4, when i use this function in my custom helper, it shows following error.

> Call to undefined function get_instance()

How can i load view file in helper in CI 4 ?

Comment: You can try replace `$ci = &get_instance();` with `$ci = get_instance();` More details is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58766038/get-instance-is-not-working-in-codeigniter-helper-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: Why don't you try this library [https://github.com/SyedMuradAliShah/codeigniter4-template-library](https://github.com/SyedMuradAliShah/codeigniter4-template-library)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for any of that.

In codeigniter 4 all you need to do is:

```
if ( !function_exists('render_admin_view') ) {
        function render_admin_view($filename, $data) {
            $dir = config('admin_dir');
            echo view($dir . 'common/header', $data);
            echo view($filename, $data);
            echo view($dir . 'common/menu', $data);
            echo view($dir . 'common/footer', $data);
        }
}
```

More information about using views here: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/outgoing/views.html?highlight=views

If you want to return the views, just store it in a variable and return the contents of those variables.

Having said this, using helpers to load views is not ideal. You want to do that in your controllers. Or if you want to render sections or even have different layouts, you should look into view layouts that codeigniter 4 provides.

Comment: You resolve my issue, can you tell me where i can set `config('admin_dir');` ?

Comment: That should be in your App/Config folder setup as a class that you can then load in your helper as you would any other class or with the config helper.